# Video de mi animation cambia de color en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android

Estoy usando MvideoView y en algunos dispositivos el color de background del video cambia de color y se ve bastante feo ps este es apenas un recuadro en medio de la pantalla que ademas tiene un background con el mismo codigo de color que del background del video, y eso en algunos dispositivos se ve en diferentes colores. Me pueden ayudar?. intente con librerias externas y nada :C

```
 MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(context);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() +"/"+resource);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);


        mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Que color estas definiendo para el videoView? veo un Transparent.

Comment: ignora eso. Si lo quito obtengo el mismo resultado :c... se ve bien en algunos dispositivos y otros no. @Jorgesys

Comment: Ok la solución es definir siempre un color de fondo al contenedor, he notado que algunos "samsung" el fondo puede cambiar de color.

Comment: disculpa creo que hago eso. mi contenedor tiene el mismo color background que en fondo de la animation en cuestion, pero en este ultimo en otras pantallas se ve diferente color, se ve mas claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final no pude dar solución a mi problema con este recurso. Obte por usar el animationView con LottieAnimation. Y esta funcionando perfectamente ademas que la calidad se mantiene bastante.